# Need help changing src for parent images in ul list

Tags: jquery, parent-child

I have a custom accordion menu with [+] link next to each expandable UL (toggle_action) to expand its child (div_toggle). For the active

(the page being viewed) I'm trying to traverse up the DOM and change any plus.gif images into minus.gif next to its parent

s since they are already expanded. I've searched for most of the day and going crazy. Below is my latest attempt that I thought was surely going to work. I don't get any errors - it just doesn't work.

Here's my HTML:

```
    <ul class="topnav">
      <li><h3 class="toggle_action"><img class="img-swap" src="/images/plus.gif"/>Governance</h3>
        <ul class="div_toggle">
          <li><h3><img src="/images/spacer.gif"/><a href="/governance">Governance</a></h3></li>
          <li><h3 class="toggle_action"><img class="img-swap" src="/images/plus.gif"/>Board of Directors</h3>
            <ul class="div_toggle">
              <li><h3><img src="/images/spacer.gif"/><a href="/governance/bod" class="active">Board of Directors</a></h3></li>    
              <li><h3><img src="/images/spacer.gif"/><a href="/governance/bod/min">Minutes</a></h3></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><img src="/images/spacer.gif"/><a href="/governance/com">Committees</a></h3></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><h3 class="toggle_action"><img class="img-swap" src="/images/plus.gif"/>About</h3>      
        <ul class="div_toggle">
          <li><h3><img src="/images/spacer.gif"/><a href="/about">About Us</a></h3></li>
          <li><h3><img src="/images/spacer.gif"/><a href="/about/contact">Contact</a></h3></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$('.topnav a.active').parents().attr('src').replace('plus.gif','minus.gif');
```

What am I doing wrong?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have your html nested, it will never grab the `<img>` tag because it is not considered a parent of the `active` class `<img>` tag.

You should consider changing the way your HTML is being outputted most definitely.

But here's a solution to your problem in the current way that you html is being nested.

```
$(".active").parents(".div_toggle").prev("h3:first").children(":first").addClass("plus");

$('h3.toggle_action img').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('src') && $(this).hasClass('plus') && $(this).attr('src').indexOf('plus.gif') > 0)
    {
        var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('plus.gif','minus.gif');
        $(this).attr('src', imgSrc);
    }
});
```

Ok, what this does, is that it grabs the `"active"` parents `<h3>` child `<img>` and adds a class to it called `"plus"` and uses this class when looping through the `<h3 class="toggle_action"><img>` tags, making sure to grab the img tag with plus as a class, and changes the other ones to the minus.gif image.

Hope this helps you.  If so, mark it as your answer.

Comment: Thanks Solomon. Unfortunately I'm kinda stuck with this html. Your code changes all of the + into - but is there any way I can apply this only to the h3 above the active <a href>?

Comment: Oh, yeah, I thought you posted all relevant `<img>` tags up, surely there's a way.  I will post more code and update my answer for just that `<h3>` tag and all `<img>` childrens within it... k?  Give me a sec.

Comment: @longboardnode - Do you want all `<h3><img>` tags from that of the `.topnav` class only?

Comment: sorry for the incomplete code. I edited it now to show you a sample of the complete list structure. So essentially I need the + next to Board of Directors and also next to Governance to turn into - (since governance/board is active) but for the + sign next to "About" to remain unchanged. Tnx!

Comment: @longboardnode - Ok, updated my answer.  Let me know if this works for your situation.

Comment: you're a lifesaver! It worked with a minor tweak: removed ! from "!$(this).hasClass('plus')" works like a charm.

Comment: Ok, great... So, this is your answer?  You're Welcome!  Was a tough one to figure out, but glad I got it for you!

Answer (score 0):

the `img` tags aren't parents of the `a` tags, they're siblings. You want to use `.prev()` instead of `.parents()`.

And `attr` is deprecated, you should be using `prop`. And you don't need to use `replace`, you can just do `prop('src', 'minus.gif')`